# How to sort user defined class in .net , c#

Tags: c#, .net, class, sorting

I have a collection of user defined class object, e.g. Car instances, what is the best way to sort it.

Below are the possible ways, which one is the best, is there other ways?

1. IComparable
2. Comparer
3. Comparison
4. IEquatable

Any idea would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's another important and extremely simple way, unless you *absolutely require* that you sort in-place: use LINQ to Objects. For example:

```
var orderedByName = cars.OrderBy(car => car.Name).ToList();
```

You can order by multiple projections, and in a varied fashion, like this:

```
var complex = cars.OrderByDescending(car => car.Year)
                  .ThenBy(car => car.Model)
                  .ThenByDescending(car => car.Make)
                  .ToList();
```

I've only put the `ToList` at the end to create a `List<Car>` at the end - if you only need to iterate over the results though, you can let it perform the ordering lazily:

```
var query = cars.OrderByDescending(car => car.Year)
                  .ThenBy(car => car.Model)
                  .ThenByDescending(car => car.Make);

foreach (var car in cars)
{
    // Use car
}
```

Personally I find this the most flexible way of sorting. Otherwise, using `IComparer<T>` and `Comparison<T>` are the next most flexible, as *anyone* can order that way. `IComparable<T>` requires the class itself to decide how items are going to be ordered, and you can only implement it once, which makes it somewhat inflexible.

`IEquatable<T>` is used for comparing items for *equality*, so is used for things like `HashSet<T>`, not for ordering.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, which solifies my understanding.

Comment: @John, THis is off the topic. I read both version of your books, c# in depth. What c# book would you recommend, apart from your books, for a c# expert. How to apply for a Software Engineer in Google?

Comment: @Pingpong: Actual *C#* language books? The specification, ideally... if you've understood C# in Depth, there aren't any books I know of that go into more *language* detail. CLR via C# and C# 4 in a Nutshell go into lots of depth on *other* fronts, mind you. As for applying to Google - ping my your CV at skeet@pobox.com.

Comment: @John, both CLR via C# and C# 4 in a Nutshell are great books, as is C# in depth. I will do that at skeet@pobox.com.